# Wireless network driver help

Tags: drivers, wireless

I've got an Acer x4610g and I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 lts and I cant find a network driver for it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you install while connected to network? Try using ethernet cable and then do a `sudo apt upgrade`!

Comment: The model of machine matters less than the chipsets contained within the machine (some make/models contain different chips during their production runs, why some makes provide service-tags...)    The following is the help page for networking https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en which provides commands like `sudo lshw -C network` (which lists hardware of class networking) that help us to know more & provide more detailed help.